# How to combine multiple chunked zip files into single file using C#.Net?

Tags: c#, file, merge, split, zip

I have to upload huge file using c# and MVC , here i can able to chunk the big file into several files using **j-query by slice(Splitting the files)** function and uploaded to server location. but i'm **not able to open the combined(merged) files** again which is coded through c#.net.

Mainly **zip,.7z files not opened properly** , rest of another files like **.mp3, .doc,.PDF , etc are opened in proper way.**

Here i attached the c# code

**Method 1:**

```
private void JoinFiles(string FolderInputPath, string FileOutputPath)
{    
    DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(FolderInputPath);

    FileStream fsSource = new FileStream(FileOutputPath, FileMode.Append);

            foreach (FileInfo fiPart in diSource.GetFiles(@"*."))
            {
                Byte[] bytePart = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fiPart.FullName);
                fsSource.Write(bytePart, 0, bytePart.Length);
            }
            fsSource.Close();
 }
```

**Method 2:**

```
{
string[] tmpfiles = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/Tamp"), "*.");

                FileStream outPutFile = null;
                string PrevFileName = "";

                foreach (string tempFile in tmpfiles)
                {
                    //string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(tempFile);
                    string baseFileName = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(".")));
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                    if (!PrevFileName.Equals(baseFileName))
                    {
                        if (outPutFile != null)
                        {
                            outPutFile.Flush();
                            outPutFile.Close();
                        }
                        outPutFile = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads/Tamp") + "\\" + baseFileName + extension, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                    }

                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    FileStream inputTempFile = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);

                    while ((bytesRead = inputTempFile.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                        outPutFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    inputTempFile.Close();
                    System.IO.File.Delete(tempFile);
                    PrevFileName = baseFileName;

                }

                outPutFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are disregarding file order it seems.

Comment: No GeirGrusom, here files are order in correct way only like ,

0000001
0000002
.
.
.
.
0000098

Comment: How do you know? GetFiles does not give any order guarantee. Your first code seems like it could work as long as either the uplodaded data is not corrupted or the files come out of order.

Comment: for rest of other files are working properly u know, for compressed files only have this type of problem..

Comment: How much have you tested this? It may be completely random which files work and which don't. In any case your C# code looks fine, so you have to verify that the order is correct for the files that don't work, and then do a diff to see what is different.